# How to get selected item in RadioGroup in React native?

Tags: react-native

How can i get selected value from RadioGroup.

```
state = {
        gender: '',

        data: [
            {
                label: 'male',
                value: "Male",
            },
            {
                label: 'female',
                value: "Female",
            }
        ],
    }

render() {
        return (

               <View style={styles.radioGroupContainer}>

                        <Text style={styles.textLableStyle}>Select Gender</Text>

                        <RadioGroup style={alignItems = 'flex-start'} 
                                    radioButtons={this.state.data} 
                        onPress={
                            this.onPress
                            } />

                    </View>

               )
         }
```

**Note: On selection of radio button i want value in gender variable.**

Comment: What data do you get in `onPress` of `RadioGroup`?

Comment: Actually i don't know how to print actual value when radio button is selected in radio group.

Comment: Can you share code for implementation of `RadioGroup`?

Comment: Here is all code apart from other designing views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-radio-buttons-group) by entering the below command in your project root directory.

```
npm i react-native-radio-buttons-group --save
```

**Basic Usage**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import RadioGroup from 'react-native-radio-buttons-group';

export default class Vertical extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        label: 'Default value is same as label',
      },
      {
        label: 'Value is different',
        value: "I'm not same as label",
      },
      {
        label: 'Color',
        color: 'green',
      },
      {
        disabled: true,
        label: 'Disabled',
      },
      {
        label: 'Size',
        size: 32,
      },
    ],
  };

  // update state
  onPress = data => this.setState({ data });

  render() {
    let selectedButton = this.state.data.find(e => e.selected == true);
    selectedButton = selectedButton ? selectedButton.value : this.state.data[0].label;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 50 }}>
          Value = {selectedButton}
        </Text>
        <RadioGroup radioButtons={this.state.data} onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Output](https://github.com/ThakurBallary/react-native-radio-buttons-group/blob/master/docs/images/react-native-radio-buttons-group.gif)

Answer (score 0):

make the RadioGroup like that , only giving the RadioGroup tag . by putting that code you will get the value in gender state.

```
<RadioGroup style={alignItems = 'flex-start'} 
    radioButtons={this.state.data} 
    onPress={data => this.setState({gender: data })} />
```

Comment: It prints like 
[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: try to do something like that and check what you get in console,  onPress={data => console.log(data)}

Comment: It prints whole data array rather than selected data value.